# Possible to have larger thumbnails in Channel Images entry screen?

Tags: devdemon, channel-images, thumbnails

I've gone through the Channel Images documentation, but didn't find this issue addressed. In the entry screen (in table form) the thumbnail of the images is quite small -- so small, that it's difficult to see which image is which when I'm working on the order of the images for a gallery. Switching to tile view doesn't work, because that gets rid of other editing options that I need.

It's true that clicking on a thumb in the table view of the entry screen brings up a large view of the image, but for workflow of determining an order of a bunch of images, it's not practical to have to constantly click open an image, then close the window, and back and forth.

Anyone know if it's possible to make the thumbs in the entry screen larger, like maybe the size they are in the tile view? If not currently, I think this would be a great enhancement and would really improve the user workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You just need to choose the small and big preview in the field settings.

[image]

However the only way to make the table bigger would be to hack the CSS for the fieldtype.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply! So the small/big preview radio buttons -- those just control the size of the preview if I click on the image in the table, but not the actual preview in the table, is that right? I'll try the hack to the the CSS for the fieldtype and see if that works. I'm guessing that's in the channel_images_pbf.css file?